# Get online presence status automatically in multiple tabs open for Strophe JS connection

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire, strophe

We are trying to implement a chat application where we are using strophe js.So when we open multiple tabs, not able to get presence status in both the tabs automatically. We get only in one tabs that too the one which was opened last. Please Help!!

Comment: Are you using a JS framework (Angular, ...) to develop your web client and which Strophe.js plugins are you using?

Comment: Yes we are using backbonejs to developr our web client and strophe.js library for XMPP BOSH/XMPP over Websocket.

Answer (score 0):

I used to develop a web xmpp client and i encountred this problem.
I used Presence Service Plugin to get presence status via HTTP requests and it's working well.

Comment: I checked out that plugin, but this plugin does not give on-going current chats for the person. What exactly you did for that ?

Comment: you just send a http request with the wanted jid. If you want to protect this request, set an autorized jid, so that you send thoose two jid and get the presence

Comment: Thank you kassav, i also wanted to get current chats going for that particular jid which this plugin is not giving. I am not sure what i am missing here

Comment: you are missing something. with this plugin you get the status for each jid. check the plugin docs